Why am I getting 401 Unauthorized on Jira Cloud REST API requests?
I’m currently developing an Atlassian Connect app that needs to authenticate requests to the Jira Cloud REST API using a JWT token. However, I keep getting a 401 Unauthorized error when making requests from my server-side code.
What I’m Trying to Do: I have a Node.js/TypeScript setup where:

I store the clientKey, sharedSecret, and baseUrl after installing the Connect app.
I generate a JWT token for each request using the atlassian-jwt
library, including the qsh claim.
I make a GET request to Jira’s /issue/CL-988 endpoint as a test.


Code snippets:

atlassian-connect.json:
{
  "name": "MyCompany Bot",
  "description": "MyCompany Bot for Atlassian.",
  "key": "com.MyCompany.bot",
  "apiVersion": 1,
  "baseUrl": "https://{AYN_IP}.ngrok-free.app/atlassian",
  "vendor": {
    "name": "MyCompany, Inc.",
    "url": "https://example.com"
  },
  "authentication": {
    "type": "jwt"
  },
  "lifecycle": {
    "installed": "https://{AYN_IP}.ngrok-free.app/atlassian/installed"
  },
  "scopes": [
    "READ", 
    "WRITE", 
    "DELETE", 
    "PROJECT_ADMIN", 
    "ADMIN", 
    "ACT_AS_USER"
  ],
  "modules": {},
  "icon": {
    "url": "https://{AYN_IP}.ngrok-free.app/atlassian/image.png"
  }
}


atlassian.service.ts:
import {AtlassianCLientV2} from "./atlassian.client"
public async getIssueV2(): Promise<any> {
    return (await AtlassianClientV2()).get("/rest/api/2/issue/CL-988")
        .then(res => res.data)
        .catch(e => {
            throw new Error(JSON.stringify(e.response.data))
        })
}


atlassian.client.ts
import axios, {AxiosInstance, AxiosResponse} from "axios";
import cache from "../utils/cache";
import * as jwt from 'atlassian-jwt';
import moment from 'moment';
import {SymmetricAlgorithm} from "atlassian-jwt/dist/lib/jwt";

  
export async function AtlassianClientV2(): Promise<AxiosInstance> {
    const installedData: ConnectHook = await cache.cache("tokens:atlassian:connect:data") as unknown as ConnectHook;

    async function createJwtToken(method: string, resource: string): Promise<string> {
        console.log(resource)
        const token = jwt.encodeSymmetric(
            {
                iss: installedData.clientKey,
                iat: moment().utc().unix(),
                exp: moment().utc().add(3, 'minutes').unix(),
                qsh: jwt.createQueryStringHash(
                    jwt.fromMethodAndUrl(method, resource)
                )
            },
            installedData.sharedSecret,
            SymmetricAlgorithm.HS256
        );
        console.log(jwt.decodeSymmetric(token, installedData.sharedSecret, SymmetricAlgorithm.HS256))
        return token;
    }

    const instance: AxiosInstance = axios.create({
        baseURL: installedData.baseUrl,
    });

    instance.interceptors.request.use(async (config) => {
        config.headers.Authorization = "JWT " + await createJwtToken(
            config.method.toUpperCase(),
            config.url
        );
        config.headers.Accept = 'application/json';
        config.headers["Content-Type"] = 'application/json';
        return config;
    });
    console.log(instance.defaults.headers)
    return instance;
}


What I’ve Checked So Far:

Verified that installedData.clientKey and installedData.sharedSecret are correct.
Confirmed that baseUrl is correct, pointing to the Jira Cloud instance (e.g., https://mycompany.atlassian.net).
Ensured that the qsh is calculated using only the relative path (e.g.,/rest/api/2/issue/CL-988) instead of the full URL. Decoded the JWT on jwt.io to verify claims look correct (iss, iat, exp, qsh).
Confirmed that my server’s time is accurate.

Despite these checks, I still receive a 401 Unauthorized response. I would greatly appreciate any guidance on what I might be missing. Are there any additional claims required, or is there a known issue with certain endpoints or HTTP methods? If you need more details, please let me know. Thanks in advance for your help!
